# Notification of available updates in terminal window

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I run Ubuntu 12.04 and if the computer is started in console mode I get a notification of available updates when I log in. Is there a way to get this notification to show up in a (GUI) terminal window? What do I need to add to ~/.bashrc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a command called `apt-check`. The following Bash script displays the number of updates if there are any:

```
updates=$(/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable)
if [ ${updates:0:1} != 0 ]; then
   echo -e "$updates"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The message that you see is from a package called `motd` aka `message of the day` from ubuntu. There are files that can be modified to remove update notification, as well as put new welcome messages, run scripts that will fetch various information to display.

Take a look at this [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/104708/how-to-customize-ubuntus-message-of-the-day/) on how to customize it.

Comment: OK, thanks, `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available` is the command I'm looking for. However, it can't be run as non-root as it creates a file in `/var/lib/update-notifier`. As far as I know you should be able to check for new updates without being root.